# `<module:H5bp>': uninitialized constant Compass::Frameworks (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

```
/home/eduardo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-h5bp-0.1.1/lib/compass/h5bp.rb:5:in `<module:H5bp>': uninitialized constant Compass::Frameworks (NameError)
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0.beta1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0.beta1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta1'
  gem 'haml-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

  gem 'compass-h5bp'
end

gem 'html5-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# To use debugger
```

I don't know what is causing this error.  I get the error when I try to run:

```
rails generate html5:install
```

Here is the project: https://github.com/sporkd/html5-rails

I have tried a couple of things that I found on Google but none have really worked.

Answer (score 3):

With compass-rails **before** compass-h5bp it works (rails 3.2.13, ruby 2.0)

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'compass-h5bp'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the compass-rails gem to the assets group fixed the problem for me.

Comment: please give more explain.(-: